# Perform action on click of sliding drawer Handler

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, slidingdrawer

In my application I want to fill the sliding draw only when data is not null.
So , when the user presses on the sliding drawer handler it should give a dialog "Data is empty" and sliding drawer should not open.

I have tried **Handler.setOnTouchListener()** but what happens is anywhere a touch event is called that dialog box appear.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the method [`setOnDrawerOpenListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html#setOnDrawerOpenListener%28android.widget.SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener%29).

Create your own [`OnDrawerOpenListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener.html) and use it to check if the data is null - if it is, close the drawer again:

```
private class OnDrawerOpened implements OnDrawerOpenListener {
  @Override
  public void onDrawerOpened() {
    if( data == null )
      mySlidingDrawer.close();
  }
}
```

You would need a reference to your `SlidingDrawer` and you would need `OnDrawerOpened` to be an inner class, so you can access the reference to your `SlidingDrawer`.

**Alternative**

You could also create your own subclass by extending `SlidingDrawer` and then override the `animateOpen()` and `open()` methods (you might need to override `animateToggle()` and `toggle()` too):

```
public class MySlidingDrawer extends SlidingDrawer {

  public MySlidingDrawer( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
    super( context, attrs );
  }

  @Override
  public void animateOpen() {
    if( data != null )    
      super.animateOpen();
    else
      //Show dialog
  }

  @Override
  public void open() {
    if( data != null )
      super.open();
    else
      //Show dialog
  }
}
```

If you do this, you would need to reference your own implementation of the `SlidingDrawer` in your XML:

```
<com.myPackage.MySlidingDrawer>
   ...
</com.myPackage.MySlidingDrawer>
```

Depeding on how and when you get the data to check for null, you might want to either pass it to `MySlidingDrawer` in its constructor or add a method through which you can set the data.

Comment: Ok , I applied this. Now whats happening is ..Drawer opens..then closes and the dialog box comes. I dont want it to open atall. :(

Comment: Check the alternative I posted above.